# WebView in Gallery stopping scroll/touch events

Tags: android, webview, scroll, touch, gallery

I am using android's gallery feature with WebViews to load thumbnails from a remote site. I'm using WebView so that it will handle caching the images for me. I have it working fine with one little issue relating to handling of touch events and scrolling the gallery.

If you happen to try and scroll the gallery starting with your finger on top of a WebView it won't scroll. The WebView is consuming the touch event.

How do I go about getting it to ignore these so they get to the Gallery?

Edit: And now it's also stopping the Gallery from getting the onItemClick events. D'Oh!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gallery.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement your gallery, overriding the onInterceptTouchEvent method and returning true from it:

```
public class WebViewImagesGallery extends Gallery {
  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      return true;
  }
}
```

in your view, reference it as:

```
<com.example.WebViewImagesGallery
                     android:id="@+id/webViewImagesGallery"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```